# Gnu Grub 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3

Tags: grub2, gnu

I installed my ubuntu 14.04 in pc alongside with win 10. Then I restart my pc and when i want to boot ubuntu, open me the window and there is:

> GNU GRUB version 2.02 beta2-9ubuntu1.3
>
> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere esle TAB lists possible device or file completions.
>
> grub>

Please help

Answer (score 0):

This will require a Live Ubuntu Media (CD/DVD/USB, the same you used to install Ubuntu). Boot from it in the "Try without installing" option. Open a terminal windows and run the following commands:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt
```

replacing X with your Ubuntu's partition number.

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda --root-partition=/mnt
sudo chroot /mnt
sudo update-grub
exit
```

Reboot and GRUB should be OK.

Comment: If you're running `update-grub`, I'd guess at least `/dev` should be mounted in the chroot.